# Docker Alpine image + grpc: Warning: insecure environment read function 'getenv' used

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, getenv

When I used this image: [node:6.11.0-alpine](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/node/tags/6.11.0-alpine/) to run my service (use GRPC), then keep getting these warnings:

```
D0622 06:52:01.170502843       1 env_linux.c:66]             Warning: insecure environment read function 'getenv' used
D0622 06:52:01.554446816      12 env_linux.c:66]             Warning: insecure environment read function 'getenv' used
D0622 06:52:01.559295167      14 env_linux.c:66]             Warning: insecure environment read function 'getenv' used
D0622 06:52:01.566036292      13 env_linux.c:66]             Warning: insecure environment read function 'getenv' used
D0622 06:52:01.569975088      15 env_linux.c:66]             Warning: insecure environment read function 'getenv' used
```

Do I miss any package? How to fix this?

This issue [Issue #8104](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8104) can be referred.

Comment: Inshi, Are you able to resolve this? I m also facing similar issue.

Comment: @sranga no, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has been fixed in grpc-1.23.0 and newer: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/commit/5efa660b41ab05971901f3a7b19e3890ea1e8884